# Refreshing SQL Server DB on Amazon RDS

Tags: sql-server, amazon-rds

we have a SQL Server DB running on Amazon RDS, i need to refresh it. But in RDS there is no option to restore a backup. What other ways i can use to refresh this DB? It is 60 GB, and has 200 tables.

Thanks

Comment: The only way we found is to use special import wizard or bcp. This was one of the reasons we do not use RDS. Forgot to mention - you will need something that will run wizard/bcp and another SQL server as a source on RDS/EC2.

Comment: If i Use BCP i have to disable all indexes and Constraints and truncate all tables .. is this correct?

Comment: Basically, yes. But easier to use [this tool](https://sqlazuremw.codeplex.com/) for Azure. It allows you to sort out dependencies effortlessly. Under the hood it uses bcp.